# Is there a way to click on a recaptcha element from a site

Tags: python, selenium, automation

So I am trying to solve a captcha through selenium. First I try to click the captcha on this website https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/. I try xpath and ID method which hasn't had any success. Could someone please help me out here. [Here is a picture of what I am trying to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBJMU.png)
Here is also what I have written. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]')
```

Comment: But captchas are designed to avoid bots. Even if you click the "I'm not a robot" checkbox you will have to solve the challenge. See [Captchas :: Documentation for Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/captchas/).

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I will be using this to try and solve in my selenium window. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buster-captcha-solver-for/mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6Ld2sf4SAAAAAKSgzs0Q13IZhY02Pyo31S2jgOB5&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYXRyaWNraGxhdWtlLmdpdGh1Yi5pbzo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=5mNs27FP3uLBP3KBPib88r1g&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=ufdnmqmcxiqv" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-y2973t5aots" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
```

Your element is in an iframe switch to it. Now your xpath should work.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```